# There's no choice to create a Python2.7 notebook in Jupyter

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7, glib, jupyter

My Jupyter notebook doesn't have a choice for creating a Python notebook. Can you please why could the reason be and how to fix it?

I expect to see something like the following:
[image]

But this is what I see after running "jupyter notebook":
[image]

```
$ jupyter notebook
[I 18:34:28.910 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:34:28.918 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/mona/libzmq/cmake-build
[I 18:34:28.918 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 18:34:28.918 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/
[I 18:34:28.918 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

(firefox:18833): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:18833): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:18833): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:18833): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
[W 18:34:33.278 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) is not available

[W 18:34:33.278 NotebookApp] Native kernel (python2) is not available
1486946551509   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for aushelper@mozilla.org did not contain an updates property
1486946551521   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for webcompat@mozilla.org did not contain an updates property
1486946551544   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for firefox@getpocket.com did not contain an updates property
1486946551555   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for e10srollout@mozilla.org did not contain an updates property
1486946551566   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} did not contain an updates property
1486946551830   addons.xpi  WARN    Add-on firefox-hotfix@mozilla.org is not compatible with application version.
1486946552022   addons.xpi  WARN    Add-on firefox-hotfix@mozilla.org is not compatible with application version.
1486946552383   addons.xpi  ERROR   Attempted to load bootstrap scope from missing directory /home/mona/.mozilla/firefox/thjcjy9j.default/extensions/firefox-hotfix@mozilla.org.xpi
1486946552383   addons.xpi  WARN    Add-on firefox-hotfix@mozilla.org is missing bootstrap method shutdown
1486946552386   addons.manager  WARN    Exception calling callback: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST) [nsIFile.isDirectory]"  nsresult: "0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: getURIForResourceInFile :: line 1537"  data: no] Stack trace: getURIForResourceInFile()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1537 < this.XPIProvider.callBootstrapMethod()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:4811 < this.XPIProvider.uninstallAddon()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:5089 < AddonWrapper.prototype.uninstall()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:7504 < uninstallHotfix/<()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm -> jar:file:///home/mona/.mozilla/firefox/thjcjy9j.default/extensions/firefox-hotfix@mozilla.org.xpi!/bootstrap.js:93 < safeCall()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:188 < makeSafe/<()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:204 < Handler.prototype.process()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:937 < this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:816 < this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<()@resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:750
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem got fixed by installing `ipykernel`

```
$ sudo pip2 install ipykernel
The directory '/home/mona/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mona/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip
Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
  Downloading pexpect-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.2MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports-abc>=0.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.ssl-match-hostname in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from tornado>=4.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=13 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.3->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel)
Installing collected packages: simplegeneric, pexpect
  Running setup.py install for simplegeneric ... done
Successfully installed pexpect-4.2.1 simplegeneric-0.8.1
mona@pascal:~/libzmq/cmake-build$ jupyter notebook
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/paths.py:54: UserWarning: Moving ~/.config/ipython to ~/.ipython
  warn('Moving {0} to {1}'.format(cu(xdg_ipdir), cu(ipdir)))
[I 18:45:16.823 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:45:16.823 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:45:16.830 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/mona/libzmq/cmake-build
[I 18:45:16.830 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 18:45:16.830 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8890/
[I 18:45:16.830 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```